# Visual/Text tabs in wp editor Not Showing

Tags: metabox, visual-editor, wp-editor, text, html-editor

I have a wordpress website that i have added custom meta boxes to the post.

Custom meta boxes have an editor using wp_editor(), but the editor is refusing to show the visual/text tabs on the editor panel.

I have deactivating all plugins on my development, and the issue persisted.

Anyone can help me ?

Comment: Can you please edit your question and provide the code you are using to add wp_editor ? That will help the community to find where the problem is and you will get advise.

Comment: One of the major reason is Yoast SEO plugin.
Make sure that Yoast SEO plugin is up to date.

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing your code I can't say whats wrong but here is a working (tested) example of a metabox with an editor inside that has the visual/text tabs.

```
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes',  function() { 
    add_meta_box('html_myid_61_section', 'Meta Box Title', 'my_custom_meta_function');
});

function my_custom_meta_function( $post ) {
    $text= get_post_meta($post, 'my_custom_meta' , true );
    wp_editor( htmlspecialchars_decode($text), 'mettaabox_ID', $settings = array('textarea_name'=>'inputName') );
}

add_action( 'save_post', function($post_id) {
    if (!empty($_POST['inputName'])) {
        $data=htmlspecialchars($_POST['inputName']); 
        update_post_meta($post_id, 'my_custom_meta', $datta );
    }
});
```

---

**Consider This...**

I don't often recommend plugins BUT I would STRONGLY suggest using [Advanced Custom Fields](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/) for stuff like this.  Its easy to learn and will save you time and frustration!  You can make professional admin layouts very fast.

Answer (score 0):

You should assign a **textarea_name** and your editor ID should not contain other symbols other than dash ( - ) and underscores ( _ ).

```
wp_editor( 'Lorem Ipsum', 'editor-id', array('textarea_name'=>'message') );
```